# Compiling dictconv on Haiku

Tags: haiku

I'm having trouble compiling [dictconv](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ktranslator/dictconv-0.2.tar.bz2?download) on Haiku nightly hrev46922.  I've never tried before.

First it complained about not knowing which OS it was.  So I followed the directions and replaced `config.sub` and `config.guess` with newer ones.  Ran it again, there are even newer ones, I guess they switched from CVS to github.

OK, ran it again, and this time it said it can't find libxml2.  So I used HaikuDepot to install libxml2.

Now I have libxml2 2.8.0-6 installed, but I just realized that libxml2_x86 was already installed, version 2.9.1-1.  Nonetheless, with two copies, it still can't find it:

```
~/Desktop/dictconv-0.2> ./configure --prefix=/boot/home/Desktop/dictconv-0.2/
[...lots of checking, without errors...]
checking for libxml - version >= 2.5.0... no
*** The xml2-config script installed by LIBXML could not be found
*** If libxml was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the XML2_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to xml2-config.
configure: error: You must have libxml2 >= 2.5.0 installed
```

Well, I searched for `xml2-config` and I don't have it.  However, I did find a file called `/boot/system/data/cmake/Modules/FindLibXml2.cmake` and happened to notice on `dictconv`'s site that I could use cmake, so I tried that:

```
~/Desktop/dictconv-0.2/build> cmake ..
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
XML2_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /boot/home/Desktop/dictconv-0.2/src
XML2_LIBRARY
    linked by target "dictconv" in directory /boot/home/Desktop/dictconv-0.2/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Lastly, I thought I'd try to get it to use the file I found:

```
~/Desktop/dictconv-0.2/build> cmake -P /boot/system/data/cmake/Modules/FindLibXml2.cmake ..
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing:  LIBXML2_LIBRARIES LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

At this point I'm in over my head already, but I kept looking anyway.  I see on [HaikuPorts](http://bb.haikuports.org/haikuports/src/53f9afc3e15c/dev-libs/libxml2/?at=master) these two recipe files, but I'm not sure how to use them to end up with what under linux is the "-devel" kind of package, which is what I figure `dictconv`'s `configure` script is looking for.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a bit of a late response, but you should just need to install the libxml2_devel package.

This isn't shown by default in HaikuDepot, so go up in the menu in HaikuDepot to the "Show" option and select "Develop packages". This should cause the correct package to be listed, allowing you to install it.

After this xml2-config should work for you as expected.

Comment: Thanks.  I cannot test this at the moment but will when I next have the opportunity.